# How do i store Facebook user profile information on a database using the Facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, social-networking, user-profile

I was able to implement a Facebook login for a social networking app i am developing for android. I used Facebook's android sdk to do so, as well as getting first/last name, gender and age and displaying it on a profile page. Now i want to know how i can store this information on a database in order to display it to other users who visit the profile. Thanks in advance! Here is the code i am using for the profile page.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    public ImageView profileActivityPicture;
    public TextView nameFirst, nameLast, age, gend, user_location;
    private String userID, email, gender, picture, birthday, name, city;
    private String profilePicUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Profile");
        }
        nameFirst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileActivityFirstName);
        nameLast = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileActivityLastName);
        age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileActivityAge);
        gend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileActivityGender);
        profileActivityPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileActivityPic);
        user_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileActivityCity);
        if(profile != null) {
            nameFirst.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, profile.getFirstName()));
            nameLast.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, profile.getLastName()));
        }

        nameFirst.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
        nameFirst.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        nameLast.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
        nameLast.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject data,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            data = response.getJSONObject();
                            if (data.has("id"))
                                userID = data.getString("id");
                            if (data.has("name"))
                                name = data.getString("name");
                            if (data.has("location"))
                                city = data.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
                                user_location.setText(city);
                                user_location.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,14);
                            if (data.has("picture"))
                                Picasso.with(ProfileActivity.this).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID+ "/picture?width=3000&height=4000").into(profileActivityPicture);
                            if (data.has("birthday"))
                                birthday = data.getString("birthday");
                                age.setText(birthday);
                                age.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
                                age.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                            if (data.has("gender"))
                                gender = data.getString("gender");
                                gend.setText(gender);
                                gend.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18);
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields",  "id,name,email,gender,cover,picture.type(large),location");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get the user data from Facebook SDK and parse that json object and save what you want if it is local db or on web. What the problem are you facing?

Comment: You can simply parse json and store wherever you want..

Comment: i want to save it to a local database for now as i work on the app. I was thinking of MySQL local database.

Answer (score 0):

When you get response in completed callback simply Parse like this

```
JSONObject jobj = response.getJSONObject();

                        if (jobj != null) {
                            try {
                                ProfileBean profileBean = new ProfileBean();
                                profileBean.id = jobj.getString("id");
                                profileBean.name = jobj.getString("name");
                                profileBean.email = jobj.getString("email");
                                profileBean.link = jobj.getString("link");
                                profileBean.last_name = jobj.getString("last_name");
                                profileBean.first_name = jobj.getString("first_name");
                                profileBean.gender = jobj.getString("gender");

                                JSONObject pic = jobj.getJSONObject("picture");
                                JSONObject data = pic.getJSONObject("data");
                                profileBean.profile_pic = data.getString("url");


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // print exception
                            }
                        }
```

here you FB data are stored in a profileBean so like this you can get your data..

Comment: Yes, i did this for saving user data and displaying it on a profile page, but what if i want another user to view that profile information as well.

Comment: For that you have to store this data to local storage. For that you can use Shared Preference or local database anyone.. But I will prefer to store data in local database..

Comment: What kind of local database should i use? MySQL? SQLite?

Comment: if you want to store data in device than you can use SQLite and if you want to store on server than you have to do more stuff and use MYSQL..